# Ran a for loop to create several symlinks at once, two of them failed and I don't see why

Tags: linux, bash, symlink

So I have a digital copy of this anime series whose filenames are in Japanese. The original files need to keep the same name, but I needed the names in a different format so I decided to symlink them. Rather than go through the trouble of manually symlinking each one, I decided to just do a `for` loop to make my links.

The directory has many files in it that I'm not trying to hit with my loop, so I run through a few tests until I get a loop that returns just the files in the directory that I want to work with:

```
[user@zodiac [Yurichan] Shigofumi]$ for i in *{01..13}*1920x1080*chi*mkv;do ll "$i";done
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1209545287 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第01話「コクハク」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx4 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1205850517 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第02話「ロケット」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx4 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 973957827 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第03話「トモダチ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1057721148 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第04話「ナミダ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1024831965 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第05話「タダイマ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 976803502 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第06話「サケビ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1018146704 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第07話「キラメキ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1503810507 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第08話「ハジマリ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1100451426 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第09話「サイカイ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1234181825 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第10話「デアイ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1136201000 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第11話「メザメ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1092508733 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第12話「シゴフミ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1218814179 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第13話(終)「ソレカラ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx4 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
```

All the files I don't care about are excluded from this list, so I'm good to write my link loop now. I run the following, and get the displayed output:

```
[user@zodiac [Yurichan] Shigofumi]$ for i in {01..13};do ln -s /path/to/directory/\[Yurichan\]\ Shigofumi/*$i*chi*eng*mkv /path/to/directory/\[Yurichan\]\ Shigofumi/Shigofumi_s01e$i.mkv;done
ln: target '/path/to/directory/[Yurichan] Shigofumi/Shigofumi_s01e08.mkv' is not a directory
ln: target '/path/to/directory/[Yurichan] Shigofumi/Shigofumi_s01e10.mkv' is not a directory
```

I then check the contents of my directory (I've cropped out all the irrelevant files for this example):

```
[user@zodiac [Yurichan] Shigofumi]$ ll
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user      user        150 Dec 25 14:19  Shigofumi_s01e01.mkv -> '/path/to/directory/[Yurichan] Shigofumi/[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第01話「コクハク」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx4 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user      user        150 Dec 25 14:19  Shigofumi_s01e02.mkv -> '/path/to/directory/[Yurichan] Shigofumi/[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第02話「ロケット」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx4 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user      user        150 Dec 25 14:19  Shigofumi_s01e03.mkv -> '/path/to/directory/[Yurichan] Shigofumi/[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第03話「トモダチ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user      user        147 Dec 25 14:19  Shigofumi_s01e04.mkv -> '/path/to/directory/[Yurichan] Shigofumi/[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第04話「ナミダ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user      user        150 Dec 25 14:19  Shigofumi_s01e05.mkv -> '/path/to/directory/[Yurichan] Shigofumi/[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第05話「タダイマ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user      user        147 Dec 25 14:19  Shigofumi_s01e06.mkv -> '/path/to/directory/[Yurichan] Shigofumi/[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第06話「サケビ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user      user        150 Dec 25 14:19  Shigofumi_s01e07.mkv -> '/path/to/directory/[Yurichan] Shigofumi/[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第07話「キラメキ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user      user        150 Dec 25 14:19  Shigofumi_s01e09.mkv -> '/path/to/directory/[Yurichan] Shigofumi/[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第09話「サイカイ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user      user        147 Dec 25 14:19  Shigofumi_s01e11.mkv -> '/path/to/directory/[Yurichan] Shigofumi/[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第11話「メザメ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user      user        150 Dec 25 14:19  Shigofumi_s01e12.mkv -> '/path/to/directory/[Yurichan] Shigofumi/[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第12話「シゴフミ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user      user        155 Dec 25 14:19  Shigofumi_s01e13.mkv -> '/path/to/directory/[Yurichan] Shigofumi/[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第13話(終)「ソレカラ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx4 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1209545287 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第01話「コクハク」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx4 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1205850517 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第02話「ロケット」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx4 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group  973957827 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第03話「トモダチ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1057721148 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第04話「ナミダ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1024831965 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第05話「タダイマ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group  976803502 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第06話「サケビ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1018146704 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第07話「キラメキ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1503810507 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第08話「ハジマリ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1100451426 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第09話「サイカイ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1234181825 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第10話「デアイ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1136201000 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第11話「メザメ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1092508733 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第12話「シゴフミ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx2 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 1218814179 Oct 19  2016 '[アニメ BD] シゴフミ 第13話(終)「ソレカラ」(1920x1080 AVC 10bit FLACx4 softSub(chi+eng) chap).mkv'
```

I don't understand why it failed with that error on those two files. I googled around for it but all I could find was stuff about copy and pasting commands transforms the `-` in the command, but that isn't the case here because 1) I wrote all the commands myself, and 2) if that was the problem they all should have failed, not just 08 and 10.

I was able to successfully create the symlink for the two failures by manually linking with the whole filename with no `*` substitution, so I'm guessing the problem lies in there somewhere. But I don't understand why those two failed but all the others succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that more than one file corresponds to

```
/path/to/directory/\[Yurichan\]\ Shigofumi/*08*chi*eng*mkv
```

and

```
/path/to/directory/\[Yurichan\]\ Shigofumi/*10*chi*eng*mkv
```

check it out, run

```
ls /path/to/directory/\[Yurichan\]\ Shigofumi/*10*chi*eng*mkv
```

Use

```
/path/to/directory/\[Yurichan\]\ Shigofumi/*$i*1920x1080*chi*eng*mkv
```

as a mask, or incorporate `第$i話`